# How to stop JavaScript from running automatically?

Tags: javascript

This is a script I use in my website.
How can I stop the script from running automatically and instead be run upon mouse click ?

```
var nbOptions = 8;
var angleStart = -360;

// jquery rotate animation
function rotate(li,d) {
    $({d:angleStart}).animate({d:d}, {
        step: function(now) {
            $(li)
               .css({ transform: 'rotate('+now+'deg)' })
               .find('label')
                  .css({ transform: 'rotate('+(-now)+'deg)' });
        }, duration: 0
    });
}

// show / hide the options
function toggleOptions(s) {

    $(s).toggleClass('open');
    var li = $(s).find('li');
    var deg = $(s).hasClass('half') ? 180/(li.length-1) : 360/li.length;
    for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
        var d = $(s).hasClass('half') ? (i*deg)-90 : i*deg;
        $(s).hasClass('open') ? rotate(li[i],d) : rotate(li[i],angleStart);
    }
}

$('.selector button').click(function(e) {
    toggleOptions($(this).parent());
});

setTimeout(function() { toggleOptions('.selector'); }, 100);//@ sourceURL=pen.js
```

example link link = http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Circle-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3/index.html

Comment: `$(document).click(function(){ your code; })`

Comment: how about you give us a structured example of the code you are talking about cause it's kind of swamped in the request response

Comment: Only include the minimum code needed to demonstrate the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  (in this case, doing so would make it obvious which part to remove...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you don't want your script to start the Animation automatically on pageload.

So you simply have to remove the lase line from the code:

`setTimeout(function() { toggleOptions('.selector'); }, 100);`

This way, the animation is only started when you manually click on `.selector button`.